# Accessing to my index.html file from a computer other than where I have Apache installed

Tags: apache2, localhost

I have Apache installed and I have a index.html file that I can access by typing http://localhost/index.html in my browser.

How can I access to my index.html from any other computer?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is your question solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that computer's IP address is 192.0.2.42, as http://192.0.2.42/index.html

*localhost* in that URL simply resolves to the loopback IP address of your machine, 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I tried that but it is not working. I'm assuming because either I don't have a fix IP or because there is any configuration I need to change in Apache Server to open ports or something like that. Not really sure. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, can't help with Apache problems, but this is very basic stuff, you should be able to find the answer in the Apache installation documentation.

Comment: I think you can get your IP from the connections menu "connection information" and would need to open "port forwarding", just a wild guess I haven't done that.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your apache server is listening on port 80 (port 80 is for HTTP traffic) . Use this in terminal,

`sudo netstat -plnt`

[image: Check status of open ports]

If you see port 80 LISTEN status, you are OK.

Next, check your public IP address. You can use some website where you can check your address. For example,  [Check IP address.](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)

If **you are sitting behind a router**, your computer gets an internal IP address assigned by the router.

You can check internal IP address by running in the terminal ,

`ifconfig`

[image: Internal IP address from ifconfig]

In this case, you need to **forward the port** 80 for incoming connections to your internal IP address. Port-forwarding procedure is usually mentioned in the manual of the particular router. An online tutorial is here [WikiHow-Port forwarding](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router).   After port-forwarding, you/somebody can access 
`http://your_public_ip/index.html`
PS- Without port-forwarding other users in your local network can access your index.html by using  `http://your_internal_ip/index.html`

**Other case:** If you are not sitting behind a router. 
Then, if you have a static IP and then `http://your_public_ip/index.html` will work.

If you have dynamic IP, then you need to check Dynamic DNS. [Wikipedia- DDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)

Answer (score 0):

From another computer type the below URL on the browser,

```
http://{server-ip}:{server apache port no.}
```

Make sure that server IP is reachable from other machine and same port no. on which apache server is listening.